# Не работает автозаполнение ключевых полей в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Создана диаграмма, таблицы и связи, но в ключевых полях не работает автозаполнение
Пробовал убрать все связи, все равно как только включаю спецификацию идентификатора выдет следующую ошибку[image: Вот эта ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: убрать эту галку в настройках Designers>Table and Database designers>Prevent saving ...

Comment: искренне не понимаю людей, которые таблицы или столбцы именуют на русском языке. еще хуже, когда вперемешку. еще видимо должна быть какая то страсть постоянно переключать языки